# JavaScript read more, read less button with dynamic data from MySQL database and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have fetched an associative array from database and the problem is that the purpose i.e. $row['purpose'] remains all the same and is set to the very last row fetched
Below is my entire PHP Script

***Note:- This question is answered and the question code is replaced with a working answer
The question has been answered and the code I provided with the question has been replaced with the code from the answer***

```
<?php
session_start();
$Write = "<?php $" . "UIDresult=''; " . "echo $" . "UIDresult;" . " ?>";
file_put_contents('UIDContainer.php', $Write);
//require 'authorize-admin.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) || $_SESSION['user'] != 'admin' && $_SESSION['user'] != '') {
    header('Location:admin-login.php');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Guest Data : NodeMCU V3 ESP8266 / ESP12E with MYSQL Database</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--<h2 align="center">NodeMCU V3 ESP8266 / ESP12E with MYSQL Database</h2>-->
    <?php include 'navbar.php' ?>

    <br>
    <label class="badge badge-info" style="font-size:50px;padding:5px;display:block;text-align:center;">Guest Data</label>

    <div style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
        <table width="1000" class="table" style="border-top-color:#343a40;border:2px solid #343a40;font-size:20px;">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Guest No.</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">RFID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Gender</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Address Line 1</th>
                    <th scope="col">Address Line 2</th>
                    <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
                    <th scope="col">Purpose</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                include 'database.php';
                $pdo = Database::connect();
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM guest ORDER BY guest_no ASC';
                //$sql = 'SELECT Employee.emp_no,Employee.name,Employee.email,Employee.address_line_1,Employee.address_line_2,contact.mobile_no,car.car_num,car.Ccar_type,user.rfid_no FROM Employee INNER JOIN user on Employee.email=user.email INNER JOIN contact on contact.CONemp_no = user.u_emp_no INNER JOIN car on car.Crid_no = user.rfid_no ORDER BY Employee.emp_no ASC';
                $result = $pdo->query($sql);
                $index = 0;
                foreach ($result as $row) {

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['guest_no'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td scope="row">' . $row['rfid_no'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['gender'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['address_line_1'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['address_line_2'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['mobile_no'] . '</td>';
                    if (strlen($row['purpose']) > 50) {
                        $str = '<span id="dots' . $index . '" style="overflow-wrap:break-word;max-width:300px">' . substr($row['purpose'], 0, 20) . '...</span><span id="more' . $index . '"><span>';
                        echo '<td><div style="overflow-wrap:break-word;max-width:500px">' . $str . '</span></div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary " onclick="myFunction(' . $index . ',\'' . $row['purpose'] . '\')" id="myBtn' . $index . '" style="vertical-align-top;">Read more</button></td>
                                <script>
                                function myFunction(id,purpose) {
                            
                                var dots = document.getElementById("dots"+id);
                                var moreText = document.getElementById("more"+id);
                                var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn"+id);

                                if (dots.style.display === "none") {
                                    dots.style.display = "inline";
                                    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
                                    moreText.style.display = "none";
                                } else {
                                    dots.style.display = "none";
                                    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
                                    moreText.style.display = "inline";
                                    moreText.innerText = purpose.toString() ;
                                }
                                }
                                </script>';

                        echo '</tr>';
                        $index++;
                    } else {
                        echo '<td><div style="overflow-wrap:break-word;max-width:300px">' . $row['purpose'] . '</div></td>';
                    }
                }


                Database::disconnect();
                ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a href="guest-registration.php" style="float:right;margin-right:40px;"><label class="btn btn-primary"><b style="font-size:20px;">+</b>Add new user</label></a>

    </div>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('.gData').classList.add('active');
        document.querySelector('.home').classList.remove('active');
    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you foreach you should pass the actula values of $row['purpose']

```
 .....
 <script>
 function myFunction(id , $row['purpose'] ) {
 ....
```

and in js function so you get the actual value

```
function myFunction(id, purpose ) {

var dots = document.getElementById("dots"+id);
var moreText = document.getElementById("more"+id);
var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn"+id);

if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
} else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
    moreText.innerText =purpose ; // here you have actual value  
    
       }
}
```

Comment: I tried as per your suggestions and now i'm getting an error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' I tried something like ```<button class="btn btn-primary " onclick="myFunction('.$index.','.$row['purpose'].')" id="myBtn'.$index.'" style="vertical-align-top;">Read more</button></td>``` in foreach loop ad i am getting error in this line only

Comment: Hey once again, I solves the error thanks for your help @scaisEdge, I figured out what the problem was and managed to solve it.....in foreach loop i did something like this ```<button class="btn btn-primary " onclick="myFunction('.$index.',\''.$row['purpose'].'\')" id="myBtn'.$index.'" style="vertical-align-top;">Read more</button></td>```, and i place a condition on textbox in other script to not accept single quote and double quote and everything works fine

Comment: @Uzair   . single quote removed